# JS code not working for safari but working fine on chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript

```
$("form[name^='dwfrm']").find($("button[class$='add-to']")).on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var styleNum = $(this).prev('#pid').val();
    var applyName = $(this).attr('name');
    var wishlistform = $(this).parents('form:first').serialize();
    var url = Urls.wishlistForm;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: wishlistform + '&' + applyName + '=x',
        method: 'POST',
    }).done(function(response) {
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'addToCartFromWishList',
            'category': 'Product',
            'action': 'Add to Cart',
            'value': styleNum,
            'label': 'Wish List'
        });
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

This code works fine on chrome but on safari it is not working. any help is appreciated

Comment: What error is Safari giving in the console and when is the code being called?

Comment: My guess would be that it's using a promise somewhere... If that's the case, you can add a Promise pollyfill.

Comment: Since it's using jQuery, I'd expect it to have a built-in polyfill.

Comment: Is the code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: `$(this).parents('form:first')` is better written as `$(this).closest("form")`

Comment: What is `window.dataLayer`? And what's the point of pushing onto a variable and then immediately reloading the page? Any variable changes will be lost during the reload.

Comment: `$(this).prev('#pid')` is supicious. Do you have multiple elements with `id="pid"`? IDs are supposed to be unique.